# How does Kubernetes determine which node to use?

Tags: kubernetes

I am researching using Kubernetes on baremetal for our application. There's an issue I can't find info about. If a worker node dies, how does Kubernetes determine which node(s) to redirect its workload to? What I'm mostly worried about is that if a node dies due to being overloaded with work, Kubernetes will redirect its workload and another node will die due to the workload increase, which leads to a domino effect of nodes dying. How does Kubernetes prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid this kubernetes reserves resources on the nodes for its daemons. See full explanation and configuration guidelines [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/)